# Guidelines for build a .Net web application that can use "plug-in" data access layers

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, web-applications, architecture

I'm building an application which will initially use SQLServer 2008 as the DBMS. How should I structure my application so that at a later stage I can use a different DBMS, e.g. Oracle, without changing my code i.e. via configuration only.

I suspect my core application will call code in an assembly/layer that encapsulates all the database calls required for the application to function. This layer will then call a DBMS-specific layer (based on config) to make the actual DB call? Can anyone point me to a clear example of this?

Thanks!

Added an explanation below:

My thought was that I could have multiple assemblies e.g. MyApp, MyApp.Database, MyApp.Database.SQLServer, MyApp.Database.Oracle, etc.

MyApp would make a call like:

```
DataSet ds = MyApp.Database.GetSomeData();
```

...which looks like...

```
public DataSet MyApp.Database.GetSomeData()
{
  return GetDataFromDBMS();
}
```

GetSomeData is a generic call i.e. MyApp needs "GetSomeData()" in order to do something. It doesn't care where the data is from.

Then, GetDataFromDBMS would know, via a configuration file, to call either MyApp.Database.SQLServer.GetTheData() OR MyApp.Database.Oracle.GetTheData(). These methods could do whatever is required to get/process the data from each DBMS.

Comment: I'd love to develop on an application where they actually **do** swap out the database layer so this type of functionality is worth the efford. Sadly never been the case so far in my career.

Comment: @BenCr +1 for the comment; I find that it's usually novice/amateur developers who spend lots of time *thinking* about things like this - especially when there are so many frameworks out there that do almost all of that already.

Comment: @BenCr - Andrew Barber has a hidden agenda here. We had a disagreement and I accused him of "playground tactics", exemplified by his comment above, don't you think? I'll quote it here because he has a habit of removing his comments: "... I find that it's usually novice/amateur developers who spend lots of time thinking about things like this..."

Comment: To clarify, so that Andrew may remove his comment gracefully, in embarrassment: We are developing an application that will SPECIFICALLY supports multiple DBMS backends. The requirement to switch between DBMS-specific layers is CRITICAL so that we can support our end-users' preferred DBMS. Does that sound like a good reason to everyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should look at doing is either use an ORM tool that abstracts the database for you (nHibernate), or define a set of interfaces that represent your DAL and then use an IoC implementation (Ninject, Castle, etc) to swap out the underlying implementation at will, so long as it implements the interface.

However, designing an interface that is future-proof (ie, can cope with subtle quirks of working with other databases) is not simple, so you could end up needing to make changes anyway.

I'd do one of two things, in this order:

1. Review if you **really** need to swap out databases.
2. Go down the ORM tool route as a lot of leg-work is done for you.

A good example of abstracting a database, not necessarily the DAL per-se is the Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block from Microsoft.

Comment: The reasoning behind this is to sell the application as a product that will support the customers' preferred DBMS. The DAAB would allow me to switch providers but this pushes all the DBMS specific logic back INTO the DBMS itself (i.e. the app calls stored procs that are identically named in each DBMS). Perhaps that's a good thing, however I could envisage situations where we'd need custom .Net code to pre/post-process DBMS calls. I'd love to know how to swap at least one assembly layer in/out to do this.

Comment: Actually - can't I just do this using something like a "DALFactory" that returns either a SQL or an Oracle object that each implements an interface containing all the calls required by the core application?

Comment: @jqwha that would pretty much be the solution given by using an IoC framework.  You ask for the configured object behind an interface, but only ever use the interface in code.  Interface-based programming has limitations, but usually don't cause problems.  If you are selling this, I'd say spend a lot of time defining your interfaces as you may not be able to change them without incurring breakages.

Comment: Continued this in a slightly different thread at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637729/swapping-assemblies-to-implement-dbms-specific-functionality