# Swapping assemblies to implement DBMS-specific functionality

Tags: asp.net, database-connection, architecture

(continuation of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635530/guidelines-for-build-a-net-web-application-that-can-use-plug-in-data-access-la), but thought it was different enough to start a new thread)

I want to write an application that will allow the eventual customers to use their preferred DBMS (SQLServer, Oracle, etc) for the backend.

I could have the main app call a "Factory" object, located in a separate assembly, that will return a DBMS-specific object that implements a common interface containing all the calls required for DB access. However, this means having the compiled code for all possible DBMS systems deployed with every installation. The factory just chooses the configured assembly.

Could someone comment on this alternative method? : I could create separate assemblies for each DBMS that all use the same namespace e.g. MyDBMS, and implement the same interface. Upon installation, we'd only deploy the assembly for the customer's chosen DBMS. By changing the build configuration so that the assemblies all get the same name, COM ID, etc. then the main app wouldn't know the difference. I've tested this and it seems to work very well.

Just wondering about the pros/cons of this? The main benefit is that we could supply additional/updated DBMS DLLs without any other redeployment.

Thanks

Comment: Have you heard about ORMs? This is a solved problem.

Comment: Yes, it's possible: this is how DBMS drivers work (except they have different names while sharing the same interface/contract). If you do use swapping assemblies then you just trade *where* the configuration is done (file-system vs. configuration entry, for instance) -- I really can't see what this gains. But, as Oded as pointed out, there are likely more benefit/cost-efficient methods which could be employed.

Comment: @Oded.  You removed the link I had to a previous discussion which did discuss ORM but did not solve my problem. This is a different solution (which may be part of SOME ORM solutions, but is not a panacea). Also, from wikipedia: "In addition, heavy reliance on ORM software has been pointed to as a major factor in producing poorly designed database". So I'm not keen on ORM as a "hammer/nut" solution for my small problem.

Comment: I have not removed it, I simply used a hyperlink.

Comment: @pst. The solution above seems so minimal and direct from a cost/benefit perspective. I'll just have to check out ORM a bit more I guess if it could give me even more

Comment: @jqwha the power of an ORM tool is that it usually also removes the generation of the database also.  nHibernate also provides its own query interface on top of a given database, something that re-inventing would be a big undertaking.  What specifically is pushing you away from an ORM tool other than a slightly code-generated database?

Comment: @pst that also tends to be my approach, but I then take responsibility for the storage mechanism underneath.  I think the OP is really only concerned with the storage mechanism being interchangeable with a minimum of support or extra coding.  The OP's DAL may then sit on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ideally**, and I suggested it in passing in your previous thread, go for something like nHibernate, an ORM tool.  In most situations where the database design does not deviate from the norm too much, this will work fine.  On some large-scale applications, basically ones with performance improvements in things like stored procedures, ORM tools will start to impose limitations.

You could look the other way and say that I support multiple databases by only using behaviour common across them all.

ADO.NET provides a series of interfaces that most major providers use: `IDbCommand`, `IDbConnection`, `IDbTransaction`.  The downside here is you usually cannot take advantage of provider-specific functionality or improvements.

The Data Access Application Block in Enterprise Library does this.  You could go this route, and if you encounter the need to have something specific, you could then change the EntLib code to support your application's specific requirement.

This way, you get the bulk of the logic done for you.  If you then hit problems (you might not) you then have access to the source code in order to address it.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it's possible**: this is how DBMS drivers -- such as those in ADO.NET -- work (except they have different names/assemblies while sharing the same interface/contract).

If swapping assemblies are used over a configuration then *it is a trade where the configuration is done* (file-system vs. configuration entry, for instance). There are some things that need to be considered such as strong-names and explicit versions.

I can not justify just swapping the assembly and some advantages for requiring the configuration entry (instead of swapping) are:

1. Other parameters such as credentials or options can also be easily stored/passed in to the factory/activator.
2. It's just as trivial to keep the assembly names different which is less confusing: *which* DAL is `thedall.dll`? (If the version, etc, are the same, the only thing to go on is some check-sum or de-compilation or 'info' method. Not very fun.)
3. Can have multiple back-ends installed at once which can simplify distribution packages and testing, etc.
4. Do not need to control the build steps as much. Do not need to to "hijack" GUIDs or all claim to be the same version.

One tool I have used in the past is iBATIS and there is [iBATIS.NET](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/). It is not in the same "ORM class" as Hibernate or Active Record, etc, as it is a simple mapper between defined SQL statements and objects. Very primitive, yes. Requires lots of SQL, yes. But some people swear by it.

Happy coding.